# SSL on SIM800 , certificate select issue

Tags: ssl, sim800

I am having some issues while working with SIM800. I am trying to upload SSL certificate but it is not going through. I created a certificate saved it in .cer format. I wrote the certificate in SIM800. I am able to read the content of cer file also. But somehow simcom gave an error when I tried AT+SSLSETCERT.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have specified the path and name of file properly.

Following are command and log file from my test setup.

```
AT+FSLS=\
User\
@bt\
@btmtk\
@BTMre\
myserver_net.crt

OK
AT+FSFLSIZE=\myserver_net.crt
+FSFLSIZE: 1911

AT+SSLSETCERT="\myserver_net.crt","ABCD123"
+SSLSETCERT: 0
```

As you can see , the import is successful.
But I have other problems after this step. The SIM800C is not able to GET or PUT with FTPS. I get error 1,80 or 1,64 . So first see if you get solution for your problem as above and then let me know if you are able to transfer files.

Comment: No. I am not able to upload/download files still. What about your problem status ? Are you able to write cert file. and if so, are you able to do file transfer ?

Comment: I got a reply from SIMCOM. They said I cannot use the self-signed certificate. Only default certificates, which are pre-installed, only can be used.

Comment: I am using certificate issued by GoDaddy and working perfectly fine for browsers and ftp clients on PC . I am unable to make it work with SIM800C. What they mean by 'default' and pre-installed certificates ? Can you tell me what is the support mail ID from which you got the reply ?  I am unable to get right support contacts.

Comment: Guys, also having the same trouble with SIM800L - can set the cert but after any commands that use `CIPSSL=1` or `HTTPSSL=1` just fail (the module itself actually seems to restart). Did anyone get any further with this?